# How to clone a repository with GitHub client that I can push into?

Tags: git, github

Apology in advance if what I'm asking doesn't make any sense: I'm completely green when it comes to Git. First project I'm putting on GitHub. The software in question is multi-platform. A single feature change typically involves working in several different environments (hosted in virtual machines on my Windows workstation, with the exception of OSX for which I use my Macbook). Right now with SVN, I've been just committing changes for each OS as I made them. That's clearly not a good way to do things since that means checking stuff into the repository that'll break elsewhere. So what I want to do is to have a local repository where I can push everything into from the various environments before a final push up to GitHub. When I tried to push changes into the local repository set up by the GitHub Windows client though, Git complained about not being able to push into a non-bare repository. I didn't find an option for cloning a repository as bare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can use branches. You could have your main branch, or as you call it, your 'github' repository and then one branch for each platform, and then every feature you want to work on, is a new branch of the platform-branch, if you want the SAME feature-branch on every platform-branch, then you can `rebase` the feature-branch to the platform-branch.

Other option is to have different [remote repositories](http://gitref.org/remotes/).

Another way to go is forking the master project, one [fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo) for each platform.
It may be cleaner to you, you can even merge your fork into master.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not really comfortable with this "a new branch for every feature change" idea, but I suppose that's how git works. And bug fixes will end up being developed in their own branches as well?

Comment: I also think this is the git way, think that every feature should be a branch and being the functionality of each platform different is a kind of feature. So yes, you should have the 'master'-platform branch to contain all feature-in-platform branches.
Another way to go is forking the master project, one fork for each platform: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo
It may be cleaner to you, you can even merge your fork into master.